# socket communication in QNX

Tags: sockets, qnx

When I compare UDP socket communication between linux and QNX, I observed linux socket communication is much faster than in QNX. I written a test code to send 258MB of data to remote place using UDP sockets. Same code compiled for linux and QNX, and ran on their respective machines. I made application aware of retransmission. I observed retransmission is comparatively very less in linux than QNX. Please suggest if I need to use any QNX specific system calls, rather generic sendmsg/recvfrom.

Comment: Actual performance results, your QNX io-pkt command line, and physical network details would be useful in assisting you. Also, are you using the same hardware in both cases?